# Recognize anything which is not a number and return null

Tags: javascript

I was writing a factorial function and I wanted to add a logic that returns `null` if the user puts anything into the argument **instead of numbers** like symbols (@#!) or letters (s,z).
how can I recognize them and immediately stop my program and return `null`?
I know some ways but they will make my code really ugly and hard to read and long.

```
function factorial(n){

    let num = Number(n);

    // make num - 1 each time and push it into the list
    let miniaturizedNum = [];
    for (num; num > 0; num--){
        miniaturizedNum.push(num);
    }

    // Multiply the finalresult with the numbers in the list
    // and finalresault is 1 because zero multiplied by anything becomes zero
    let finalResault = 1;
    for (let i = 0; i < miniaturizedNum.length; i++){
        finalResault *= miniaturizedNum[i];
    }

    return finalResault;

}
```

Comment: [`if(Number.isNaN(num))`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN)? Then you can throw an error, return `NaN`, or anything else.

Comment: @evolutionxbox That would miss an empty string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming

- you want to accept both numbers and strings representing a number (and convert them to number)
- you want do avoid non integers and negative numbers since you're calcolating the factorial

  ```
  if( typeof( n ) !== 'string' &&
      ( typeof( n ) !== 'number' || Number.isNaN( n ) ) &&
      ( '' + n ).match(/^[0-9]+$/) === null ) {
      return null;
  }
  ```

Comment: This will accept `NaN`

Comment: @evolutionxbox no, the condition `( '' + n ).match(/^[0-9]+$/) === null` would be `true` in that case

Comment: combined with `&&` to the other conditions, it is false

Comment: @evolutionxbox you're right

Answer (score -2):

Check the datatype of the variable by using the typeof function, and if its not a number, then throw a TypeError

Comment: `n` is a string. And OP explicitly asked to return `null`, not throw an exception.